# Observe generic values with Combine

Tags: swift, combine, type-constraints

Take this case of a type constrained class `Parameter`, wrapping a value of given type.

Parameter conforms to the `AnyParameter` so it can be passed anywhere in the app without knowing the type. Parameters can be displayed in value cells `AnyValueCell`

- How would you do to observe the change without having to know the underlying value type? It would be nice to avoid the code repetition in the value cell `updateObserver` function
- Could `AnyPublisher` can be used here and how?

```swift
import UIKit
import Combine

print("Hello Playground")

protocol AnyParameter {
    var anyValue: Any { get }
    func set(value: Any)
}

protocol ParameterProtocol: AnyParameter {
    associatedtype ValueType
    
    var value: ValueType { get }
    func set(value: ValueType)

}

public class Parameter<T>: ParameterProtocol {
    
    typealias ValueType = T
    
    @Published var value: T
    
    var anyValue: Any { value }
    
    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    func set(value: Any) {
        guard let value = value as? T else { return }
        set(value: value)
    }
    
    func set(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}


public class AnyValueCell {
    
    var parameter: AnyParameter {
        didSet {
            updateObserver()
        }
    }
    
    var observer: AnyCancellable?
    
    init(parameter: AnyParameter) {
        self.parameter = parameter
        updateObserver()
    }
    
    func updateObserver() {
        observer?.cancel()
        
        // This is the point of the question - How to make this generic?
        // ---->
        if let p = parameter as? Parameter<Int> {
            observer = p.$value.sink() { value in
                print("Update Cell -> \(value)")
            }
            return
        }

        if let p = parameter as? Parameter<Double> {
            observer = p.$value.sink() { value in
                print("Update Cell -> \(value)")
            }
            return
        }

        if let p = parameter as? Parameter<Bool> {
            observer = p.$value.sink() { value in
                print("Update Cell -> \(value)")
            }
            return
        }
        // <----

        print("Wrong param type")
    }
}

let intParam = Parameter<Int>(value: 42)
let doubleParam = Parameter<Double>(value: 3.14)
let boolParam = Parameter<Bool>(value: false)

var params: [AnyParameter] = [intParam, doubleParam, boolParam]

print ("--> Init Cells")
let cells: [AnyValueCell] = params.map { AnyValueCell(parameter: $0) }

print ("--> Change values")
intParam.set(value: 21)
doubleParam.set(value: 1.618)
boolParam.set(value: true)
```

Result, as expected:

```
Hello Playground
--> Init Cells
Update Cell -> 42
Update Cell -> 3.14
Update Cell -> false
--> Change values
Update Cell -> 21
Update Cell -> 1.618
Update Cell -> true
```

Comment: No. I did not - Do you mean make `AnyParameter` conform to ObservableObject ? Because the cell is the observer in the story.

Comment: I see, my mistake. Then shouldn't it be wrapped with @ObservedObject?

Comment: "How would you do to observe the change without having to know the underlying value type?", okay but why ? And what do you want to do with `Parameter<T>` only printing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232709/discussion-between-moose-and-andercover).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `anyValuePublisher` property. You can (and maybe should) add it to `AnyParameter`, or you can define it in a separate protocol like this:

```
protocol AnyParameterPublishing: AnyParameter {
    var anyValuePublisher: AnyPublisher<Any, Never> { get }
}

extension Parameter: AnyParameterPublishing {
    var anyValuePublisher: AnyPublisher<Any, Never> {
        return $value.map { $0 as Any }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
class AnyValueCell {
    // ...

    func updateObserver() {
        guard let publishing = (parameter as? AnyParameterPublishing) else {
            print("Wrong param type")
            return
        }
        observer = publishing.anyValuePublisher
            .sink { print("Update Cell -> \($0)") }
    }
}
```